# How to batch authorization and public Google Appsscript?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 10 Google Appscript file, and I would let my costumer copy it to their own google drive and run it.

How to let costumer batch authorization their google drive and public Google Appsscript and return app link to me?

Comment: I cannot understand about `How to let costumer batch authorization their google drive and public Google Appsscript and return app link to me?`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: 1. customer need copy my appscript file to their own google drive
2. they publish appscript and enter script URL to web site
3. web site could working!!! using customers' appscript quota

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?